# Kali Linux webcrawling with credentials entered

Tags: kali-linux

I'm looking for a tool in which I can provide credentials and it should login the webapplication and try to crawl to pages etc.

I've found **Vega** but I have to enter a cookie. Is there a tool which I can use providing plaintext username and password?

It does not have to be natively in Kali, but it would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

How you give credentials depends on the website. If the site doesn't need
a cookie, but relies on  Basic or Digest Authentication (which are not used much in real life), you can use tools like `wget` (`--http-user`/`--http-password`) or `curl` (`--proxy-user`).

Answer (score 0):

I've found out in **Vega** I can click Identities after clicking **new scan**. I can set up a username and password using basic http authentication.

This solved my issue.